# ActionScript call a function within another function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function

I have a function (gofromTheFuture) that controls tweening objects that is then linked to various buttons, however I also want it to be called from this function below, but flash gives me this error:
Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1.

```
function exitHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        gofromTheFuture();
    }

function gofromTheFuture(evt:Event):void{
        myTimeline2.insertMultiple( TweenMax.allTo([TheFutureArtwork, pausebutton, playbutton, Verse, Chorus, Verseto1, Verseto2, Chorusto1, Chorusto2, rewind, fastforward, progressline, progressbar, TheFutureComments],
        0.25, {x:"450", autoAlpha:0, onComplete:exitAnimation}) );
        }

        function exitAnimation():void {
        trace("Return to main menu.");
        gotoAndStop(1, "Menu");

        }
```

How do I call this gofromTheFuture from within this function?
Thanks

Comment: You're missing arguments for `gofromTheFuture()`, can you post that function? Either that or you're trying to call `exitHandler()` without an Event.

Comment: Are you trying to call exitHandler directly?

Comment: I have another button that needs the preventDefault so I made this new function called exitHandler that executes when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change `gofromTheFuture()` to:

```
function gofromTheFuture(evt:Event = null):void
```